# The purpose of MVC API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im trying to undertand how to use the API Controller in ASP.NET MVC.

As default, the methods are Get, Post, Put, Delete.
I should using this against the Knockout framework. But im trying to understand if i can extend the api controller to return more complex data, or should the api controller just handle CRUD?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: "Web API uses the HTTP method, not the URI path, to select the action."
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api
You can change this behaviour by modifying the route as this article points out:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do anything you want. Web API is just extension to regular controllers, that allows you to create easily consumable webservices with content negotitation and easier data querying.

By default, method are decorated with certain attributes for you to be aware, that you should use GET for data extraction, DELETE for deletion, POST and PUT for creation, modification. This is just a template to start properly.

First example on ASP.NET Web API page doesn't use CRUD:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api